# WP Metabox not saving post meta

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes, post-meta

i am trying to implement a simple checkbox on the page, in order to dynamically add a Html chunk in case the user choses it, but i am unable to save the post_meta to perform this task, can someone help me? The value taken from this checkbox input is not been save on the post meta information.

This is what i got so far on my functions.php

```
function wporg_add_custom_box(){
    $screens = ['page', 'wporg_cpt'];
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'wporg_box_id',           // Unique ID
            'Entra in Flee Block',  // Box title
            'wporg_custom_box_html',  // Content callback, must be of type callable
            $screen,                   // Post type
            'side'
        );
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wporg_add_custom_box');


function wporg_custom_box_html($post){
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wporg_meta_key', true);
    ?>
    <label for="wporg_field">Add "Entra in Flee" block to page</label>
    </br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="wporg_field" id="wporg_field" class="postbox">
    <?php
}


function wporg_save_postdata($post_id){
    if (array_key_exists('wporg_field', $_POST)) {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_wporg_meta_key',
            $_POST['wporg_field']
        );
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'wporg_save_postdata');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the $value on wp_cusotm_box_html function.
I think it should be somthing like this:

```
function wporg_add_custom_box()
{
    $screens = ['page', 'wporg_cpt'];
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'wporg_box_id',           // Unique ID
            'Entra in Flee Block',  // Box title
            'wporg_custom_box_html',  // Content callback, must be of type callable
            $screen,                   // Post type
            'side'
        );
    }
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'wporg_add_custom_box');
function wporg_custom_box_html($post)
{
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wporg_meta_key', true) ? 'checked' : '';
    ?>
    <label for="wporg_field">Add "Entra in Flee" block to page</label>
    </br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="wporg_field" id="wporg_field" class="postbox" <?php echo $value; ?>>
    <?php
}

function wporg_save_postdata($post_id)
{
    if (array_key_exists('wporg_field', $_POST)) {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_wporg_meta_key',
            $_POST['wporg_field']
        );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_wporg_meta_key'
        );
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'wporg_save_postdata');
```

Comment: The checkbox doesnt uncheck if i do it and save the page. Any idea on what might be happening?

Comment: yeah, the code only updtes the post_meta if the checkbox is checked. I updated my answer to consider when it's not checked

Comment: What does this line mean/do? `'wporg_custom_box_html',  // Content callback, must be of type callable`

Comment: it calls the function "wporg_custom_box_html" which is written a few lines below in the code..
basically that function is generating the html that appears in the metabox ( a label and an input in this example).